# add random force and direction to rigidbodies every x seconds

Tags: unity, rigidbody

i need to add a `windForce` to multiple `rigidbodies`, with random direction and random force every x lapse of time. I'm using `InvokeRepeating` to update the `windDirection` so that the rigidbodies can be pushed in a different direction every x seconds.

Here's the code:

```
void windRotate()
{
    windDirection.y = Random.Range(0, 360);
    transform.Rotate(windDirection * smooth);

    if (objectsInWind.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (Rigidbody rigid in objectsInWind)
        {
            rigid.AddForce(windDirection * 10);
        }

    }
}
```

This way the rigidbodies don't receive any force. I guess the system does not recognize the `Vector3` Update of `windDirection`, so I need to recalculate it, bit I was not able.
On the other hand if I use this:

```
rigid.AddForce(Vector3.Up* 10);
```

the rigidbodies moves but in one direction only, and it's not updated on the next `windDirection` change.
I tried playing with the various Vector3 values (up, right etc..) and different force methods (`AddRelativeForce`) but nothing changed.

By using `Debug.Log(windDirection);` i know that `windDirection` is updating correctly ever 3 seconds, so it should also be updated in my methods when i apply the force, but id does not work.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: At the top of your function, it looks like you're using `windDirection` as a triplet of angles. But when you call `AddForce`, you're using it as a cartesian vector. Did you mean to construct a cartesian vector pointing along the angle specified in `windDirection`? If so, it looks like you left that step out.

Comment: I initialized `windDir` as Vector3 because the `Rotate` requires a Vector3, and Quaternion are not allowed. Do you mean i need to add  something like:         `Vector3 newAngle = new Vector3(0, windDirection.y, 0);` inside my `windRotate` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want something like this:

```
// This is an angle triplet, not a cartesian vector, so don't call it "direction".
// Also, since you're applying a relative rotation, you probably want your range
// to be symmetric about zero, so you rotate clockwise as often as counter-clockwise.
windAngle.y = Random.Range(-180, 180);

transform.Rotate(windAngle * smooth);    


Quaternion windOrientation = Quaternion.Euler(windAngle);

// Now we've converted our angles to a cartesian vector pointing in that direction.
Vector3 windDirection = windOrientation * Vector3.forward;

foreach (Rigidbody rigid in objectsInWind)
{
     rigid.AddForce(windDirection * 10);
}
```

Or, if you want to use the direction your object is facing, you can get that easily with `transform.forward`:

```
foreach (Rigidbody rigid in objectsInWind)
{
     rigid.AddForce(transform.forward * 10);
}
```